# Facebook externalhit_uatext robot lowercasing urls

Tags: facebook, url

I'm working on a site that has mixed-case urls, similar to youtube. We generate IDs on the server, and I chose base 62 (numbers, lower and uppercase letters) so they would be shorter. So the urls might be something like `example.com/user/123AbCaBc` The facebook robot seems to be hitting my site regularly with an all-lowercase version `example.com/user/123abcabc` This causes a 404 error as the all-lowercase ID isn't in the database.

According to the logs, there aren't other user agents creating 404s, so this is for sure a robot and not a human. Here's the user agent I'm seeing:

`facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

This happens about once every 4 minutes. I'm not currently logging non-404 hits, so I'm not sure if there are others to the non-lowercase version.

The server tech here is nodejs / mongodb, but I don't see how that is relavant to the issue at hand.

Is there something I can do to fix facebook? Is there a problem here, or should I squealch these log errors? Anyone else have a similar problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that you Node "Webserver application" (are you using Express?) currently doesn't support byte ranges. The Facebook crawler apparantly has the behaviour to fallback on lowercasing the URL as described here:

- https://mail.habari.co.tz/pipermail/linux/2013-June/000180.html

Have a look at

- http://derickbailey.com/2014/04/28/check-http-byte-range-request-header-with-nodejs-and-expressjs/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813480/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-Node-js

on how to fix this.

Comment: I need to spend some time looking into this, implementing it, and getting it up to production. If this turns out to be the issue, and your suggestion fixes it, I'll happily re-open the bounty and award it to you.

Comment: That's fine, no worries. Good luck!

Comment: As StackOverflow doesn't seem to account for "hey it may take more than 24 hours to see if this is the correct answer or not" I'm awarding you the bounty. Hopefully it solves the problem, and if it does I'll probably write up a blog post and link to it here detailing the problem and my solution. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have solved it. After adding partial content handling to my site, I'm still seeing facebook 404s in the logs for lowercased IDs. www.bloxi.com is the site.

Comment: That's bad to hear. I just checked some random url on your site, and it's seems fine to me: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloxi.com%2Fblock%2FSbEWFaB%2Fview%2Fbazinga-which-big-bang-theory-character-are-you Did you identify some cases when it gets transformed to lowercase (sample link)?

Comment: We've not been able to consistently reproduce what causes the urls to be lowercased. It has happened with a number of different pieces of content. Often that content is shared on facebook, or sometimes we promote it with facebook ads, or sometimes people comment on the content and follow a notification into our site. We're thinking that some mobile device that we're not testing with may be causing the issue.

Comment: This is still happening. How ridiculous. We have a bunch of URLs that simply don't exist if you lowercase the URL, and they all 404.