# Facebook Sharing: home page of my server

Tags: facebook, share

I have a big issue for a few months ...
When sharing a facebook page (if I copy the URL in a new Facebook status, for example), the image and description generated by Facebook is not at all that of my site, but homepage of my website.

example:
www.passisagesbijoux.com

Accessible without worries from my browser. When I put the URL into a facebook status he me out of my server page "87.106.242.7" ...

On this server I have several field and it does the same for them.
I want to say that everything worked on 09.22.2014, the date of my last Facebook publication.

I looked on the developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ software
The return code is 206, and the information is that of my "87.106.242.7" obviously ...

I do not know how strictly fix the problem ...

If anyone can help me is gladly!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you added the OpenGraph tags to your site?

Comment: My home page is not called, although I inserted open graph that will not change the concern I think ... It would be perhaps a DNS problem, I do not know what Facebook uses.

Comment: Can you give a sample URL which isn't working?

Comment: www.passisagesbijoux.com work in browser. But don't work if copy/paste in your facebook statut...

Answer (score 0):

Your website is missing the appropriate OpenGraph tags. Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/

You should add the tags to the `head` portion of your site, something like

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{app_id}" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="{url}" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="{title}" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="{image_url" />
```

and fill all the `{parameters}` with the appropriate values. Then sharing should work seamlessly.

Comment: Look my other site : http://www.nowis-informatique.fr/

The graph does not show good party ...
https://graph.facebook.com/10151081626280324

And when looking at the scrap, we realize that it does not scrawl the right place (I think it http://87.106.242.7 scrawl the website)
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowis-informatique.fr%2F

Comment: Why do you reference another URL now? I thought it's about  
www.passisagesbijoux.com and this site does NOT contain Opengraph tags as it should if you want to share this.

Comment: Because i think it's not the problem... Look with www.nowis-informatique : the meta is correct, but Facebook don't go in my homepage... He go in my server homepage... The problem isn't OpenGraph...

Comment: Code 206 means partial content (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). I'd think that your server can't handle Range Header requests, similar to the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628275/facebook-externalhit-uatext-robot-lowercasing-urls/27776816#27776816

Comment: Ok i see... But I have not installed NodeJS or Express... How could I solve this simple problem (I'm not draw sheet with servers ...)

Comment: What webserver are you running? Have a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/ and

Comment: I have Parallels Plesk 12.0.18

Comment: That's not a webserver... Inspecting the headers results that you're using Apache.

Comment: Doing a `curl -I http://www.nowis-informatique.fr/assets/front/img/slider/2/-tincelles-                                                                    de-couleurs_480x480.png` shows that your server apparantly supports range headers: `Accept-Ranges: bytes` so that's not the problem. Then, I don't know. Maybe open a bug report with Facebook

Comment: On http://www.nowis-informatique.fr
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 10:31:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 13:01:20 GMT
ETag: "20681-21b8-4f3db9dfefb51"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 8632
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: On file .png (last comment) : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 10:33:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: On file .png with arg -4 on curl, it's OK